# Can't Publish Application to Android Market

Tags: android, google-play

I just developed my first game on Google Android. I'm trying to submit it the store. I paid my 25$ and went through all the steps.

When I'm at the part where I have to upload screenshots, I get this error:

> Unable to parse response. If you have a browser extension or add-on
>   installed which changes the JSON response, please disable and refresh
>   this page.

I tried this on Chrome, Firefox, and IE. I don't have any extensions that would be doing any of this.

I've seen some other people post on Stackoverflow, but their posts (from what I could see) are from at last year... so is this a bug everyone is experiencing?

Comment: try upgrading your browsers, that may help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is still a common issue

https://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/forum/#!category-topic/android-market/technical-help/8emO_DadgxI

My solution was to wait until my account was confirmed.

Answer (score 0):

Try uploading the app by Re-Creating the screenshots. Try creating the screenshot using DDMS.